# Cannot Edit The User Form with Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

On the devise gem github it says to edit the form for new users and signing in you first make them available by doing:

rails generate devise:views

which I did and it generated the necessary views such as:

app/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb
app/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb

etc.

Yet when I go to edit these forms it doesn't have any affect on what is being rendered. I can remove letters or do anything to the code and it still loads the way it was originally. Is there something else I need to do to get it to work? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you restarted your sever?

Comment: Looks like you have wrong paths. Views must placed under app/views/devise directory

Comment: Thank god! That was it and damn was that frustrating. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have wrong paths. Views must placed under app/views/devise directory